# Very big amount of rows in MySQL about 1000000000, need advice

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

We have about 200000 goods in DB. And about 1000 cities. What we need is to store every change of the price of each product in every city in DB for about 6 months. I calculated and it turns out, that I wil have about 1000000000 rows in my MySQL table. 
Is it ok or maybe I have to use another logic? What will be the performance of reading data from such big table. What engine is better for that - MyIsam or InnoDB? I didn't work with such big tables, please give an advice. Thank you!

Comment: How did you calculate that billion rows? Are the cities going to average a million price changes each every 6 months?

Comment: Performance will most likely depend on your structure, indexing and hardware.

Comment: Prices can change every day, because we aggregate prices of shops

Comment: my best advice is to avoid as much as you can to duplicate info between rows. For example: all data that describe a good should be in a table (goods_head). If you assign each good an unique id you can then store in another table that id, the price and the date when the price was recorded. It will make the db more readible. Then I'd index the second table on good_id and date (assuming these are the criteria you will search the data).

Comment: Lelio Faieta: yes, thats exactly our  structure, but after some month I'll have some hundred of million rows in that table with prices and dates. I have hardware: Intel® Core™ i7-4770 Quadcore Haswell – 4 cores, 32 GB DDR3 RAM, Maybe my logic of DB structure is not the best? Will I be able to work with billion table?

Comment: If you're developing this new, rather than ask "what's the fastest way" in advance, try a design with a representative test set, and see if the performance is actually a problem.  A billion rows is a lot, but you don't know what fast and slow mean until you see it in action.

Comment: It will also *greatly* depend on what kind of queries you intend to run on this data.  Further, in your hardware specs there, you didn't list the storage, which is likely to be an important factor on a database this big.

Answer (score 0):

Your hardware is ok.

InnoDB.  `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 22G` for your 32GB of RAM.

Use the smallest practical datatype for each column.

A billion rows is possible.  But some queries will be slow -- due to disk speed.

Show us the queries; then we can discuss indexes and perhaps partitioning.